# Ordering by subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to select the newest threads (Thread) ordered descending by the time of the most recent reply to them (the reply is a Post model, that's a standard forum query). In SQL I'd write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM thread AS t ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(posted_at) FROM post WHERE thread_id = t.id) DESC
```

How do I do such thing in SQLAlchemy? I tried something like this:

```
scalar = db.select[func.max(Post.posted_at)].where(Post.thread_id == Thread.id).as_scalar()
threads = Thread.query.order_by(scalar.desc()).all()
```

But it seems that I don't understand how scalars work. Reading docs for the 5th time won't help. Could someone help me write such query in SQLAlchemy? I use flask-sqlalchemy and MySQL for this app.

Comment: other than the missing parenthesis following select that's exactly how it works, order_by(select().(..).as_scalar().desc()), the Thread.id should correlate to the parent query automatically.  you'd need to put more detail here as to what's "not working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks fine to me, here's a test:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thread(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thread'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    thread_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thread.id'))
    posted_at = Column(String)

s = Session()

scalar = select([func.max(Post.posted_at)]).where(Post.thread_id == Thread.id).as_scalar()

q = s.query(Thread).order_by(scalar.desc())

print q
```

output (note we're just printing the SQL here):

```
SELECT thread.id AS thread_id 
FROM thread ORDER BY (SELECT max(post.posted_at) AS max_1 
FROM post 
WHERE post.thread_id = thread.id) DESC
```

looks pretty much like your query

Comment: Thanks, temporarily moved from PyCharm to Sublime Text and that's the result :) Error thrown looked like query was invalid, not like syntax was erroneous.