# Sorting the sum of two subqueries

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm wanting to sort the top performers based on the sum of two different queries. How can I do this?

Let's say I'm tracking player stats for a tournament and have these models:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1024), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    dob = db.Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
    start_ts = db.Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), nullable=False)
    end_ts = db.Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
    school_id = db.Column(db.String(1024), db.ForeignKey('school.id'), nullable=False)


class School(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1024), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    address = db.Column(db.String(80))
    state = db.Column(db.String(2))


class GameStats(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1024), primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), nullable=False)
    player_id = db.Column(db.String(1024), db.ForeignKey('school.id'), nullable=False)
    scored = db.Column(Numeric(0, 0), nullable=False)
```

I'd like to produce a report formatted like this:

```
player.id | player.name | total_score (scored from day 1 + day2) | school.name | school.state
```

for the top 10 players sorted by total score. What would the simplest way to do this be? I'm fine using either python/sqlalchemy or sql.

Comment: Did you try using [`order_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by)?

Comment: No I have not, I'll look at it. I'm a little less familiar with subqueries, so I wasn't quite sure how to add two together, especially since the two queries only differ on the date filtered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering by subquery in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516672/ordering-by-subquery-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**via SQL:**

```
SELECT
    player.id,
    player.name,
    SUM(gamestats.scored) AS total_score,
    school.name,
    school.state
FROM
    player
    INNER JOIN school
    ON player.school_id = school.id
    INNER JOIN gamestats
    ON player.id = gamestats.player_id
WHERE
    gamestats.date >= <whatever day 1 is>
    AND gamestats.date <= <whatever day 2 is>
GROUP BY
    player.id,
    player.name,
    school.name,
    school.state
ORDER BY
    total_score DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The method in which you limit the 10 results can change based on the type of SQL you're using. LIMIT 10 works with netezza, SELECT TOP 10 works with microsoft sql, etc, etc.